# Why Google Play doesn't show relative games for my game?

Tags: android, google-play, publishing

I've created a game. It is already a week old but nothing is being displayed in relative apps only "More from developer".

This is my game:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.clownstudio.icancount

What am I missing? Do I have to wait a little longer? Or maybe there is a checkbox in developer console that I don't see?

Comment: How much approximately, and maybe algorithm is known?

Comment: It took 3 weeks for my game